# How To Convert a Decimal From 123.45 into 0000000012345 using C#

Tags: c#, currency

I have a requirement in doing some conversion work to send over a decimal field into a zero filled string.

```
I need to turn 1234.56 into 000000000123456
```

I know I can multiply by 100 to get rid of the decimal (not my favorite thing to do), but then how can i format it to match the requirement?

I'm assuming there's some kind of built in Format method, i just can't find it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd try this: [How to: Pad a Number with Leading Zeros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd260048.aspx)

> You can pad an integer with leading zeros by using the "D" standard
>   numeric format string together with a precision specifier. You can pad
>   both integer and floating-point numbers with leading zeros by using a
>   custom numeric format string. This topic shows how to use both methods
>   to pad a number with leading zeros.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65277/are-link-only-answers-poor-practice

Answer (score 2):

This will do it:

```
string.Format( "{0:D15}", 123456 );
```

You should consult the documentation for [string.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx).

Comment: will this handle decimal removal?

Comment: No, I'm afraid you will have to do that yourself.  The *D* format specifier will throw an exception if you give it a float, it needs an integer type.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx You could do it by using the following format:

```
Decimal value = new Decimal(1234.56);
            Console.WriteLine("I need to turn {0} into {1}", value, value.ToString("000000000000000"));
```

Regards,
herber